# Infer specific type from an object associated to a specfic object's key

Tags: typescript

I have a registry object in a shape of `{[key]: <T>()=>T}`, the `T`s can be absolutely anything as I want to easily add more entries into it in the future. I then have a function accepting registry key as string and this function should then return a value of the associated generic type. But I can't get it to work, because it returns union of generic types returned by all the functions in the registry.
The description is kind of unwieldy, so I hope the simple working example describes what I intend to do in enough detail.

```
type valFn<T> = () => T

declare const stringFn: valFn<string>;
declare const numberFn: valFn<number>;

const registry = {
  alpha: stringFn,
  beta: numberFn,
  // ... i want to easily add some records in the future without modifying +registryEater+ every time i do so, all the records will be of type +key: ValFn<Something>+
};

// CHANGES CAN BE MADE ONLY DOWN FROM HERE
type ReturnType<T> = T extends valFn<infer R> ? R : never
const registryEater = <T extends keyof typeof registry>(registryKey: T): ReturnType<typeof registry[T]> => {
  const desiredFn = registry[registryKey];
  const desiredValue = desiredFn();
  // TS2322 because +desiredValue+ is string | number, but i need it do be a specific type depending on real value of +registryKey+
  return desiredValue;
};
// CHANGES CAN BE MADE ONLY UP FROM HERE


const thisIsString = registryEater('alpha');
const thisIsNumber = registryEater('beta');
```

I can get it work by changing `return desiredValue;` to `return desiredValue as ReturnType<typeof registry[T]>;`, but isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: If you want the compiler to follow your logic you need to refactor the types as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  For your example it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzaArm). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that looks good. An answer with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't really do much type analysis on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, like `ReturnType<typeof registry[T]>`.  If you want to write your function in a way that the compiler "understand"s, you should refactor to use *distributive object types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to start with a very basic mapping type like

```
interface RegistryReturn {
    alpha: string;
    beta: number;
}
```

and then represent your other operations as [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on that:

```
type Registry = { [K in keyof RegistryReturn]: () => RegistryReturn[K] }
const registry: Registry = {
    alpha: stringFn,
    beta: numberFn
}
```

Your generic function could then just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type, and things work:

```
const registryEater = <K extends keyof RegistryReturn>(
    registryKey: K
): RegistryReturn[K] => {
    const desiredFn = registry[registryKey];
    const desiredValue = desiredFn();
    return desiredValue; // okay
};
```

The `desiredFn` variable is seen to be of type `Registry[K]`, and then `desiredValue()` is seen to be of type `RegistryReturn[K]`, specifically because `Registry` is defined as a mapped type as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.

---

So that compiles as desired, but unfortunately it re-defines `registry` in terms of `Registry`, which you're not allowed to do.  Instead, your requirement is that `registry` is given to you and cannot be modifierd.  Luckily we can just define the `RegistryReturn` mapping type in terms of it:

```
type RegistryReturn = { [K in keyof typeof registry]: 
  ReturnType<typeof registry[K]> 
}
```

And then just assign `registry` to a new variable of type `Registry` so that the mapped type lookup still happens:

```
const registryEater = <K extends keyof RegistryReturn>(
    registryKey: K
): RegistryReturn[K] => {
    const _registry: Registry = registry; // new variable
    const desiredFn = _registry[registryKey];
    const desiredValue = desiredFn();
    return desiredValue; // still okay
};
```

That still compiles.  The only thing left to do is make sure callers get the behavior they want:

```
const thisIsString: string = registryEater('alpha'); // okay
const thisIsNumber: number = registryEater('beta'); // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#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-BehK2B6t1gYCAByLy+J9EORQRIfP5wED79RbhPDgADkdGiMQdXDfAG1DR8ny1d9P2-VhfxAIA)